# Using Redux-Saga in New Redux template react app

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga, redux-thunk

The new redux has a template built in for store and all the necessary thing to start a react redux app but it is using redux-thunk under the hood to make async calls. It it not possible to replace this with redux-saga instead of thunk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redux Toolkit allows you to [customize the list of middleware you're using using the `middleware` option of `configureStore`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/configureStore#middleware), same as if you're creating a Redux store with the base `createStore` API.

You can completely replace the [default list of pre-defined middleware](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/getDefaultMiddleware) by providing your own `middleware` array, or call `getDefaultMiddleware()` and add your own middleware to the array and use that.

So, my advice would be to do:

```js
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  middleware: getDefaultMiddleware().concat(sagaMiddleware)
})
```